# Error: Could not find or load main class - Whenever I make a new Java file

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently working on a group project. We are using Eclipse to make a Java program and using e-git (Eclipse extension) to work together.

For some reason today, whenever I try to make a new Java file in the package, it  shows me the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class projectPackage.filename

I have no idea what is causing the error as it was working fine yesterday.

Comment: The 'could not find or load main class' message is usually shown when one attempts to execute a Java class that has no `main` function. In your case an error dialog appears each time you do `File > New > Class`? Or later when you validate the new Java class form?

Comment: This is happening during the **New Class** wizard?

Comment: maybe Project/clean and rebuild would help ...

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you have create a new package and try to create a Java file there?